# Returning hashmap keys in order of value in Java?

Tags: java, stream, hashmap

Is there a way to do this? I was thinking it could be done with streams but I'm not super experienced with them and would like some help regarding that.

For example: If the hashmap is currently like:

"A" : 5

"B" : 2

"C" : 4

You then return ["A", "C", "B"].

Answer (score 1):

```
 Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = unsortMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: I think you mean `comparingByValue`.  Also, the OP just requested the keys, you don't need to return a map.

Comment: Yes, what would the altered stream look like? Also, to strengthen my understanding of streams, could you perhaps break down what this code does? I understand you get the `entrySet`, turn it into a stream, sort based on a `Comparator` provided by `comparingByKey`, then collect it back, but I don't quite understand what's within the `collect` method, or more specifically, the `toMap` method, both with the double colon and the lambda expression.

Comment: considering the question, I think it is clear that the OP wants to retrieve all keys in a sorted way. Not the whole map sorted

Answer (score 1):

You can use TreeMap it will give you ordered by keys

```
List<Character> sortedKey() {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet()) {
        list.add((Character)entry.getKey());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.sort` approach:

1. convert HashMap to List
2. sort list using `custom comparator`
3. then create list of `key`(sorted order based on their values)

code:

```java
// function to sort hashmap by values
public static List sortByValue(HashMap < String, Integer > hm) {
  // Create a list from elements of HashMap
  List < Map.Entry < String, Integer > > list =
    new LinkedList < Map.Entry < String, Integer > > (hm.entrySet());

  // Sort the list
  Collections.sort(list, new Comparator < Map.Entry < String, Integer > > () {
    public int compare(Map.Entry < String, Integer > o1,
      Map.Entry < String, Integer > o2) {
      return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
    }
  });

  // put data from sorted list to hashmap
  List < String > temp = new ArrayList < String > ();
  for (Map.Entry < String, Integer > aa: list) {
    temp.add(aa.getKey());
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
Map<String,Integer> map = Map.of("A",5,"B",2,"C",4);
```

This is relatively simple.

- stream the `entrySet` and sort in reversed order using the Entry comparator for values.
- then get the key and collect to a list. If you return a set, they may not be in sorted order.  Nor can you access elements in a set as easily as a List, even if a `LinkedHashSet` is used to preserve order.

```
List<String> keys = map.entrySet().stream()
.sorted(Entry.<String,Integer>comparingByValue()
        .reversed()).map(Entry::getKey)
        .toList();  // java 16+ -- prior to Java 16 use .collect(Collectors.toList())

System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[A, C, B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new List of Map.Entries and sort List using method [Map.Entry.comparingByValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--) witch returns a comparator that compares Map.Entry in natural order on value and then turns it in reverse order:

```
List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
list.sort(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed());
System.out.println(list);
```